# How I can use my browser to write notes?

Tags: browser

How we can use our **browser** as a *notepad*, and avoid using other tools?
It will give the flexibility to immediately take note of urls or other stuff at the same place!

Instead of using browser extensions like evernote or other tools like notepad/gedit etc, is there some way to write down notes or copy/paste contents in browser window?

Comment: Plenty of plugins, bookmarklets and webpages to do that. For example, you can note URLs using Evernote, Pocket, Delicious... But this is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it solicits recommendations, and is not a programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming in any way.

Comment: Wow, at least you have checked 'answer' to admit its use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite interesting piece of info!

Just type the following in your browser address bar:

```
data:text/html, <html contenteditable>
```

And here you go, you are now ready to write in the window below!
Also you can mark it favourite and save as 'notepad utility' in your bookmarks!

For more info check [here](http://lifehacker.com/5980134/turn-any-browser-window-into-a-quick-edit-notepad)!

Comment: Wow, you made a programming-related and on-topic answer to an utterly off-topic question. Fun answer! :)

Comment: Ya, that was pretty interesting to me as well! So thought of sharing to all!